# Find the curves orthogonal to the family $\{y=x+1+c\cdot e^x\ : c\in R\}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonality

Exactly what it says in the title.

**My attempt:**

If we derive the equation with respect to $y$, we get that
$ 1 = \dot{x} + c e^x \dot{x}$ and thus $\dot{x}=\frac{1}{1+ce^x}$.

Therefore the differential equation describing the orthogonal trajectories is $\dot{x}=-(1+ce^x)$.

I do not know how to solve this equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First delete $C$:

$y'=1+Ce^x$ so $Ce^x=y'-1$ and $y=x+1+y'-1$ so $y'=y-x$. Then the orthogonal family has the differential equation $\dfrac{-1}{y'}=y-x$. Solve this and find the family!

Comment: Which gives $$y=-W\left(k e^{x-1}\right)+x-1$$
where $W(x)$ is the Lambert function,  the principal solution for $t$ in $x=t\,e^t$